# Laravel hasManyThrough with condition returns empty result

Tags: laravel

Here's my Customer.php model file.

```
public function orders()
    {
        if(isset($this->company->is_fleet)){
            return $this->hasManyThrough(
                'App\Models\Order',
                'App\Models\CustomerVehicle',
                'fleet_id', // Foreign key on customer_vehicles table...
                'vehicle_id', // Foreign key on orders table...
                'company_id', // Local key on customers table...
                'id' // Local key on customer_vehicles table...
            );
        }
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order');
    }
```

When I try to make;

"with" condition, It returns empty result.

etc.

```
$detail = Customer::with(['orders'])->find($customer_id);
```

returns empty

and

```
$detail = Customer::with(['orders' => function($q){
            $q->where('status', 1);
        }])->find($customer_id);
```

returns empty, too.
but If I dont use "with" condition, I can use it on blade file with "$detail->orders" method.

Comment: Just mention the table name `$q->where('orders.status', 1);`

Comment: It doesnt work. If It would be about "where" condition, my first code should have been worked. (wit(['orders']) )

Comment: I think you should re-think the logic there. `$this->company->is_fleet` may be `true` for the first Customer, not the second. Laravel doesn't know that. If you think about it, it means it would do a query for each Customer. Which it's not the point of eager loading.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier the code provided shows a search for a single customer by ID.

Comment: So question one is, what does `$customer_id` point to? Is it a customer with a `hasMany` or a `hasManyThrough` relationship to `Order`? Why include that code and then not tell us which state causes the problem?

Comment: @miken32 `Customer::with(['orders'])` This mean it could be any customer and since Laravel doesn't know **yet** what customer you're referencing to, it cannot be done. Once you have your customer, your condition can be appllied, that's why it's working afterward.

Comment: It's exactly the same as expecting to see `id` if you `dd($this->id)` in the relationship while doing `Customer::with(['orders'])->get()` or `Customer::with(['orders'])->find(1)` in both case `Customer` is not a model with an id. but `$customer->orders()->get()` will dump the id since at this point it is.